# MYSQL TRIGGER with DECLARE value

Tags: mysql, triggers, declare

I want to set value using declare on trigger. The trigger is as follow:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_queue_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `encounter_note` FOR EACH ROW DECLARE is_exist INT;
  SET is_exist = ( SELECT count(*) FROM practice_last_updated_module WHERE practice_id = NEW.practice_id );

IF NEW.enc_source = 'OP' THEN
UPDATE practice_queue_list PQL SET
PQL.vital_check = IF (NEW.vs_weight <> 0 OR NEW.vs_height <> 0 OR NEW.  vs_temperature <> 0 OR LENGTH(NEW.vs_blood_pressure) > 0 <> NEW.vs_pulse <> 0 OR NEW.vs_respiration <> 0, 1, 0)
WHERE PQL.encounter_id = NEW.id AND PQL.practice_place_id = NEW.practice_id;
END IF;

IF is_exist > 0 THEN
      UPDATE practice_last_updated_module SET encounter = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) where practice_id = NEW.practice_id;
ELSE:
    INSERT INTO practice_last_updated_module (practice_id, encounter) VALUES (NEW.practice_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()));
END IF;"
```

But it returns error on saving

> The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
>   TRIGGER `update_queue_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `encounter_note`
>   FOR EACH ROW DECLARE is_exist INT; SET is_exist = ( SELECT count(*)
>   FROM practice_last_updated_module WHERE

What's wrong with the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [13.6.1 BEGIN ... END Compound-Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html).

Try (maybe you need to use DELIMITER):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `update_queue_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `encounter_note`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN -- <- BEGIN
  DECLARE is_exist INT;
  SET is_exist = ( SELECT count(*) FROM practice_last_updated_module WHERE practice_id = NEW.practice_id );

  IF NEW.enc_source = 'OP' THEN
    UPDATE practice_queue_list PQL
    SET PQL.vital_check = IF (NEW.vs_weight <> 0 OR NEW.vs_height <> 0 OR NEW.vs_temperature <> 0 OR LENGTH(NEW.vs_blood_pressure) > 0 <> NEW.vs_pulse <> 0 OR NEW.vs_respiration <> 0, 1, 0)
    WHERE PQL.encounter_id = NEW.id AND PQL.practice_place_id = NEW.practice_id;
  END IF;

  IF is_exist > 0 THEN
    UPDATE practice_last_updated_module SET encounter = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) where practice_id = NEW.practice_id;
  -- ELSE:
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO practice_last_updated_module (practice_id, encounter) VALUES (NEW.practice_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()));
  END IF;
END// -- <- END

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: got it, after adding BEGIN and END, it works. thanks